# How to Pass an Argument Into a Java File?

Tags: java, arrays, file

So I have two Java files. One is a console program, the other is a GUI. If the user enters a command in the console program, it opens up the GUI. Pretty simple. That's done via `SettingsWindow.main(new String[0]);`.

My goal is I would like to pass arguments into `SettingsWindow.java`. I see `new String[0]` and I bet that's where I put the arguments, but I couldn't figure out how to put a string in (whether through `array` or just `String`) without it giving me an error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like below:

```
SettingsWindow.main(new String[]{"param1", "param2"});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to expand a bit on the other answers, although correct.

Java classes that have a `public static void main(String[] args)` method can be executed from the command line with the `java` command.

Arguments passed on the command line are available as the Strings in the `args` array.

In your situation the application, including the SettingsWindow class on its classpath, is already running and users can enter commands into it. When that happens, the GUI class is called, but it is not 'executed' in the same way as when starting a fresh Java application. The SettingsWindow class is already part of the application and could be called via any other method, not necessarily `main`.

In addition to passing parameters from the command line, one can also provide environment variables with `-DsomeName=someValue`. These variables override the System properties in the runtime so "someValue" would be returned by calling `System.getProperty("someName");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in an array. You already are but its just size 0. To pass info you should use something like this

```
    SettingsWindow.main(new String[] {"info", "more info"});
```